# Mule 4 Close connection SFTP

Tags: sftp, anypoint-studio, mule4

I have a simple Flow that write on SFTP folder. When it finish to write it keep on connection. 
Is possible to close the connection with the SFTP server when the file has been written?

Thanks.

Comment: you can write a small java code to close the connection after completion of transfer

Comment: Thanks for your response but I need a standard mode to close connection, not custom code.

Comment: what version of mule are you using. I read that mule support released a patch in version 4.1.3 for handling connections properly. i will try to find that thread and will share with you if that would be on any help.

Comment: Thanks Satish, do you mean the runtime version or SFTP component version?

Comment: i was referring to runtime. But this link might be more useful. https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00004mXVPtSAO/how-to-close-sftp-connection-after-upload-file-in-to-remote-server-using-mulesoft